# What is the best way to go from KMZ file to PDF using .NET stack? Silverlight nice but not required

Tags: .net, silverlight, pdf, pdf-generation, kmz

I need an application to produce a PDF file using several different custom templates.

I have a kmz file that defines my input geographic shapes, labels & coordinates.

The output needs to be for 8 1/2" x 11" normal paper, or for 32" x 36" plotters

My application uses a C# .net stack and a web service where I have access to SQLServer spatial functions.

I would like to implement it as part of my web silverlight application, but if I need to have a separate desktop application I will take that.

I need a solution quick, and the boss will pay for it - so a commercial library is OK.

My silverlight application is at http://MyDistrictBuilder.FloridaRedistricting.org

An example KMZ file is at 
http://censusvalidator.blob.core.windows.net/mydistrictbuilderdata/Public%20Redistricting%20Plan%20Submissions/HPUBC0005_Kelly_Henry_KMZ.kmz

A example output PDF file is at
http://censusvalidator.blob.core.windows.net/mydistrictbuilderdata/Public%20Redistricting%20Plan%20Submissions/HPUBC0005_Kelly_Henry_8x11.pdf

UPDATE:
I'm thinking I can use ComponentOne C1pdf library in my silverlight app.

1. Get shapes with lat/lon points from my database
2. Convert them to x/y coordinates 
   (not quite sure about this, but some other posts here may help)
   (Also not sure about getting the right paper size)
3. open a C1pdf document
4. draw the shapes to the document using C1pdf.

Any experience out there with ComponentOne?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but I've waited long enough for some feedback, so here is what I wound up doing:

I went with the Component One Silverlight Studio.  At $1200 bucks, it's a little steep, but it works great.  I used the C1pdfDocument and C1pdfViewer to integrate a pdf solution right into my web based silverlight app.  The users click a button, I generate the pdf into a memory stream and load it into the viewer.

**Lessons Learned:**

1. I did have a little trouble with drawing colored polygons, till I realized that C1pdfDocument only takes an opacity of 1.0, anything else shows up as no color at all.
2. I needed to convert my lon/lat points to x/y coordinates, and flip the vertical access since I'm drawing shapes in Florida (Northern hemisphere), and then move the x/y to the origin of the box I was drawing in.  It took me a little time to get it right, so I figured I'd post it here. Note that I don't use a lot of fancy sperical or conical projections, the simple conversion works close enough for my purposes.

Hope this helps somebody.  (If it does, give me an upvote, eh?)

```
    public void AddFillPolygon(List<Point> points, Color color)
    {
        DrawMainPolygon(points, color, mapBorderWidth, mapBorderHeight);
    }

    public void AddZoomFillPolygon(List<Point> points, Color color)
    {
        DrawTampaPolygon(points, color);
    }

    private void DrawMainPolygon(List<Point> points, Color color,  
                                   double borderWidth, double borderHeight)
    {
        double lonMin = -87.8;
        double lonMax = -79.9;
        double latMin = 24.29;
        double latMax = 31.11;
        DrawGenericPolygon(points, color,  
                                   lonMin, lonMax,  
                                   latMin, latMax,  
                                   borderWidth, borderHeight);
    }

    private void DrawTampaPolygon(List<Point> points, Color color)
    {
        double lonMin = -82.855;
        double lonMax = -82.07;
        double latMin = 27.57;
        double latMax = 28.175;
        DrawClippedPolygon(points, color,  
                                   lonMin, lonMax,  
                                   latMin, latMax,  
                                   tampaWidth, tampaHeight, tampaCursor);
    }

    private void DrawGenericPolygon(List<Point> points, Color color, 
                                   double lonMin, double lonMax, 
                                   double latMin, double latMax, 
                                   double borderWidth, double borderHeight)
    {
        Point[] XYPoints = ConvertLatLonToXYList(points, lonMin, lonMax,  
                                   latMin, latMax, borderWidth, borderHeight, 1);
        ShiftXYPointsToOrigin(XYPoints, mapBorderCursor);
        pdf.FillPolygon(color, XYPoints);
        pdf.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Colors.Black, 0.25), XYPoints);
    }

    private void DrawClippedPolygon(List<Point> points, Color color, 
                                   double lonMin, double lonMax,  
                                   double latMin, double latMax,  
                                   double borderWidth, double borderHeight,  
                                   PDFCursor clipCursor)
    {
        Point[] XYPoints = ConvertLatLonToXYList(points, lonMin, lonMax, latMin, latMax, 
                                    borderWidth, borderHeight, 6);
        ShiftXYPointsToOrigin(XYPoints, clipCursor);
        pdf.SetClipRect(new Rect(new Point(clipCursor.x, clipCursor.y),  
                                   new Size(borderWidth, borderHeight)));
        pdf.FillPolygon(color, XYPoints);
        pdf.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Colors.Black, 0.25), XYPoints);
        pdf.ResetClipRect();
    }

    private static Point[] ConvertLatLonToXYList(List<Point> modifiedPoints,  
                                   double lonMinValue, double lonMaxValue,  
                                   double latMinValue, double latMaxValue,  
                                   double borderWidthX, double borderHeightY,  
                                   int roundDecimalPoints)
    {

        Point[] XYPoints = new Point[modifiedPoints.Count] ;
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var z in modifiedPoints)
        {
            XYPoints[index] = ConvertLatLonToXYPoint(z, lonMinValue, lonMaxValue,  
                                   latMinValue, 0.0, 0.0,  
                                   borderWidthX, borderHeightY, roundDecimalPoints);
            index++;
        }

        return XYPoints;
    }

    public static Point ConvertLatLonToXYPoint(Point latlon,  
                                   double lonMinValue, double lonMaxValue, double latMinValue, 
                                   double xScaledMin, double yScaledMin,  
                                   double xScaledMax, double yScaledMax,  
                                   int roundDecimalPoints)
    {
        Point result = new Point();
        double scale = (float)(xScaledMax - xScaledMin) / (float)(lonMaxValue - lonMinValue);
        double offsetX = lonMinValue * scale - xScaledMin;
        result.X = latlon.X * scale - offsetX;

        // use the same scale to adjust lattitude
        double offsetY = latMinValue * scale - yScaledMin;
        result.Y = latlon.Y * scale - offsetY;

        // The y value is inverted on the map, because lat/lon origin (for florida) is at bottom right
        // x/y origin (for PDF document canvas) is at top left
        // this means for y values number comes out inverted and we have to flip it
        result.Y = yScaledMax * ((yScaledMax - result.Y) / yScaledMax);

        return result;
        //return (double)Math.Round(result, roundDecimalPoints);
    }

    private void ShiftXYPointsToOrigin(Point[] points, PDFCursor originCursor)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < points.Length; index++)
        {
            points[index].X += originCursor.x;
            points[index].Y += originCursor.y;

        }
    }
```